# How can I print two arrays to a page, separated by a comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to be able to store a song, and the corresponding artist in two different arrays, and then marge them together separated by a comma.

```
string[] songs = new string[3]; 
songs[0] = "Song One"; 
songs[1] = "Song Two"; 
songs[2] = "Song Three"; 

string[] artists = new string[3]; 
artists[0] = "Artist for Song One"; 
artists[1] = "Artist for Song Two"; 
artists[2] = "Artist for Song Three";
```

How can I `Response.Write` it like the following format:

Song Info: Song One, Artist One

Song Info: Song Two, Artist Two

Song Info: Song Three, Artist Three

Can I use something like this? :

```
string[] PrintToPage = songs.Concat(artist).ToArray();
```

I don't understand how I could acheive this?

*(Agreed, I could just use one Array but I want to learn).*

Comment: What if arrays have different size?

Comment: Look at Enumerable.Zip and String.Join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to combine array members at same index:

```
var output = string.Join(" ", songs.Zip(artists, (s, a) => $"Song Info: {s}, {a}"));
```

Comment: Hello. Please forgive me for being a bit thick, but why do I get a: Unexpected character '$'

Comment: Interpolated Strings were added in c# 6. If you're using previous version, you can go with `string.Format("Song Info: {0}, {1}", s, a)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
var outputString = string.Join(" ", GetSongDescriptions(songs, artists));

private IEnumerable GetSongDescriptions(string[] songs, string[] artists)
{
    for (i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
    {
        yield return string.Format("Song Info: {0}, {1}", songs[i], artists[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are songs correlate to artists by array index? If so, you can [zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) them together and convert to string:

```
var songsInfo = songs.Zip(artist, (s, a) => $"Song info: {s}, {a}");
var songsInfoStr = string.Join(" ", songsInfo);
```

And write `songsInfoStr` to response.

Comment: Thanks, I do however get a: Unexpected character '$'